# change margins / orientation in an attachment

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm adding an attachment to an email, and i want to either change the margins to the attachment OR set the orientation as landscape. How do I do that? My css isn't working.

```
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="OpporunityAttachment" rendered="{!relatedTo.Total_Number_of_Checklists__c > 0}">

 <style>
@page {
size: 21.0cm 29.7cm landscape;
margin-top: 2.0cm;
margin-left: 1.0cm;
margin-right: 1.0cm;
margin-bottom: 2.0cm;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This may help you http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce

Comment: `size: A4 landscape;margin-top: 75px;` works like a charm for me... (the top margin is so big because I'm using a floating content hack to display logo in the header of every page). Could it be the units (cm)?